# Was Lambert being transgender known before the release of Aliens?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, alien-franchise, aliens-1986, alien-1979

The inquiry scene of *Aliens*, which has more details available in the DVD/Blu-Ray extras, shows that the character Lambert was transgender, and transitioned from male to female at birth.

Was this known before the release of *Aliens* in 1986, or was it wholly a creation of the writing team for *Aliens*?

[image: Lambert's details]

> REMARKS:
>
> Subject is Despin Convert at birth (male to female). So far no indication of suppressed trauma related to gender alteration. Subject's I.Q. at level 4.6 GMA personality at 4.2. Indicates that subject's social counts are too low for large crew, up mode status, and has been routinely assigned small crew cyrosleep mode duties which been performed adequately.
>
> Slight hyperactivity and nervousness diagnosed and Loxy-Clav M (oral ingestion) has been successful as self-administered treatment.
>
> Moderate intelligence and performance abilities did not substantially increase after security patrol navigation duties and subject was therefore re-assigned long range cyrosleep duties on cargo transports and tugs. Current assessment indicates subject should not be upgraded until after extensive full range DOQ testing and Frakes-Stephen orientation is applied.
>
> Above was never acted upon due to employment discontinuity [...]

Comment: Known by whom - the writers, or the audience?

Comment: The text isn't saying that Lambert transitioned at birth but that her name at birth was "Despin Convert."

Comment: I've read a number of things that say Despin Convert is the procedure that Lambert went through, though these are mainly fan based with the convert being taken as conversion. It says at the end of that line male to female and further down "no indication of suppressed trauma related to gender alteration". So it does appear there was a gender alteration that was undertaken, most likely at birth from the provided text.

Comment: @jwodder even not looking at the second sentence in the paragraph, I do not see how the text in parenthesis would relate to the preceding part of the sentence if "Convert" was a name instead of an indication that Lambert underwent a "conversion".

Comment: @EikePierstorff - If "Despin Convert" was an obviously male name in the future, the parentheses could be clarifying that the name at birth was different than the name on file because of a male-to-female gender transition. "Convert" would be a strange last name though, for that reason alone I think the idea that it's the name for a procedure is more likely.

Comment: @Hypnosifl that is basically what I was trying to say in response to the assertion in the previous comment. Culture wars were not what they are today in 1986, so this would have been a somewhat inconsequential easter egg in any case (speaking for Germany at least, so I might be wrong here - not sure how things were in  the US).

Comment: http://platypuscomix.com/hollywood/nostromodossier.html

Comment: My initial assumption, reading the question, was that this was a profile from DVD extras. Was this indeed a (deleted) scene released with the DVD? In which case, it would seem that (at least some of) the writers would be aware that it was a written and filmed aspect of the scene, albeit one that, as the scene was deleted, was not part of the film at the time of the release, and may not have informed any other aspect of the production.

Comment: It was a scene in the theatrical cut of the film, but the detail of the text is pretty hard to read. It was only with the release of the dvd in the late 1990/ early 2000 that they text was released in a readable format. The question is really if this was made up for this scene or did this exist before

Comment: @A.Steer: Before what?

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to prove a negative, but it seems most likely that this was something that was only added by the production crew for *Aliens* and was not part of the original conception of Lambert's character in *Alien*.

There are a number of facts that point (softly, not dispositively) toward this conclusion.  I have watched quite a few interviews with Ridley Scott about *Aliens* (including one where he was interviewed by James Cameron), as well as a number of interviews with Veronica Cartwright (for example, [this one from all the way back in 1979](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1e0IMeHOxro)).  Never once have I seen either of them mentioned the idea that the character of Lambert was supposed to have been assigned male at birth.  Quite the contrary, [in this 1992 interview](https://youtu.be/guW_eIhprGE?t=113), Scott lays out a very different conception of the characters, one that does not invoke exotic backgrounds for any of them:

> I think the characters were beautifully defined, you know, within the context of all you had to know about them.  You know, that's all you need to know.

Another observation is that this "fact" about Lambert seems only to have been in circulation since the release of high-definition DVD editions of *Aliens*.  Prior to that, the background text during Ripley's debriefing scene was basically illegible, and only with high-resolution images that could be paused without visual smearing (something that was ubiquitous on earlier VCR technology) were people able to decode the on-screen text, revealing this tidbit.

On the other hand, Lambert being transgender does seem like it was something that would have been in keeping with the original conception of the character.  One well known fact about *Alien* was that the original script written by Dan O'Bannon did not specify the genders of any of the characters.  (The fact that they are address each other almost entirely by surname went along with this thematically.)  It was not considered particularly important to the story which characters were men and which were women.  If one of them had been transgender, it seems like it would have borderline irrelevant.

On the other hand, it is clear that at the time *Alien* was filmed, the character of Joan Lambert was meant to be anatomically female.  Whatever sex she was assigned at birth, by the time the story takes place, her body was female.  The strongest indication of this fact was that she was originally supposed to be shown topless, when she and the other characters emerged from their sleep pods.  (It may even have been considered to show them all bottomless as well, but if so, that was even more quickly ruled out.)  The idea was to show the industrial egalitarianism of the crew members' situation.  They were working stiffs who had been in space together for several years, and there was basically no remaining time and energy for sexual tensions.

After it was decided which characters were to be female, some sexual elements were actually added to the script, but none of them made it into the theatrical cut of the film (director Ridley Scott's professed favorite version).  There was a scripted sex scene between Dallas and Ripley, but it was never filmed, since it seemed at odds with the tone and development of the story.  There was another brief conversation filmed between Ripley and Lambert, the two women on the crew, whether either one of them had had sex with Ash, whom Ripley had grown suspicious of.  However, this scene never made it into the film either, although it was actually used in the later recut.  So while the film was almost entirely purged of direct references to human sexuality, Lambert and Ripley seem to have been conceived during writing and production as anatomically female heterosexual (or at least bisexual) women.  However, whether Lambert's gender identity had been the same from birth or if she had been surgically reassigned was not conclusively addressed.